# How can I run a relay on Windows?

Tags: relays, windows

As the question says, how can I run a relay on Windows XP or Vista?

I have looked and can't find a solution.

I did run one from an Android tablet but that is not always on. My PC's are running 24/7 and I have a very fast fibre connection to the net. It is a shame not to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me, I'd install a virtual machine - for example, [VMware](http://www.vmware.com) - and run my relay from there, rather than trying to run it natively in Windows.

(My opinion is based around my being a Linux user... )

So, quick instructions:

- Install VMware
- Install [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download), or another Debian-based flavour of Linux, as your virtual machine
- [Configure](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-relay.html.en) the relay inside the virtual machine as per the Linux [instructions](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-relay-debian.html.en)

The virtual machine also provides another level of separation between Tor and your native system.

Comment: This seems the best idea using VirtualBox, Thanks Richard and Andrew

Answer (score 4):

The Tor Project Documentation has a page on [Configuring a Tor relay](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-relay.html.en). They point out that "since Vidalia (a graphical interface for Tor) is no longer included in Tor Browser, there are currently no easy relay packages for Windows and OS X users."

You can still do this with Tor Browser, but you'll need to leave it running the whole time. You'll need to edit `torrc` in the Tor Browser folder's `Data\Tor` folder. Open the file with a text editor and add the following lines:

```
ORPort 443
Exitpolicy reject *:*
Nickname ididntedittheconfig
ContactInfo human@...
```

You can also try using the Expert Bundle available from https://www.torproject.org/download

Answer (score -1):

I asked a similar question several hours ago [Windows 10pro x64](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/12273/running-realay-on-windows-10-pro-x64)

The first reply gave me the link to your question.

I searched for the Vidalia package which is supposed to be OK for Windows 10 including Tor Browser as part of that package, located it at; [Vidalia Bundle 0.2.4.23](http://vidalia-bundle.en.lo4d.com/)and D/L and installed i an hour ago.

Although it is working, and I am connected to Tor, it appears that "Your Tor version needs updating", which conflicts somewhat as the Vidalia package has not been updated.

I see that the Tor Community is hopefully upgrading Tor for Win10 x64.

Unsure this will assist, I keep getting an error message to "check Firewall, Hosts, Address, Ports etc - Although I am actually connected to Tor.

Perhaps someone has a better solution.

***Edited**: It's some 20 hours later, and the Vidalia suite as listed above is working perfectly.

No error messages at all, fully connected and functioning as selected: "Relay traffic for the Tor network (Exit Relay)"

It does seem that the Vidalia/Tor Software software takes quite some time to test all Ports etc, until a stable setup is automatically found, at which point the software 'Locks in' and the advisory messages tell the user it is all OK as a Relay now.

If you need assistance, just send me a message.*

Note that with the above Vidalia Suite, the version of Tor is "Out of date", but hopefully there will be an update.

Cheers :-))

Comment: 0.2.4.23 is old, it's not currently in the ["recommended" client version set](https://consensus-health.torproject.org/#consensusparams). You should use the "expert bundle" which at least has a recent Tor version. You will not, for example, be eligable for the "Valid" flag, or any flags that depend on the "Valid" flag.

Comment: Thanks for your info, canonizing ironsize, but the link you gave just above is perhaps for Linux users. It means nothing to me. What is needed is the Vidalia bundle - Tor part, updated, but it all appears to be tied todether. Further helpful addvice is always appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The link is the vote on "valid" versions of Tor. Vidalia is dead, deprecated, no longer supported and unecessary and the vidalia bundle with it. That package is over 2 years old now. For a recent version of `tor.exe` use the [Expert Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/dist/torbrowser/6.0.2/tor-win32-0.2.7.6.zip), (and check it's [signature](https://www.torproject.org/dist/torbrowser/6.0.2/tor-win32-0.2.7.6.zip.asc)).

Comment: Does that "expert Bundle" allow Setup of a Tor Relay. Mine is working OK at present. The Vidalia Suite works mostly automatically. Does the "Expert Bundle" do the job, or is there a long and involved job to get a relay working. Remember this is Win 10 Pro x64 I'm using, not Linux. Thanks for further advice

Comment: You could just point vidalia at the expert bundles tor.exe if you must insist on vidalia, but you are vulnerable to remote code execution exploits if you insisting on running ancient, unpatched code with *many* publicly disclosed vulnerabilities (libssl, not tor). If you're unwilling to put in a little effort to run a server and have no idea how to administrate one on your chosen operating system, maybe you shouldn't be running one.