# Any tor users who are looking to run relays on Windows?

Tags: configuration, relays, directory, tor-install

So this is a tool I made which allows easy operation of tor relays on Windows. Made for people who have Windows but want to run relay without pain of Linux VM.

Features:

Auto installs tor and keeps up to date

Easy configuration with sample torrc

Monitor IP addresses tor is connecting to

Add relay to start automatically when Windows starts

Drawbacks:

Only supports vanilla bridges

Configures Windows Firewall, but other firewalls still need to be configured to allow tor.

Comment: Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vpk6yvUWQqU

Comment: Not seeing an option to do this. Are you going to use it?

Comment: Not seeing how to do that.....

Comment: Hi, if you want to provide useful information, please answer a question. There is one about [running a relay in Windows](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/7437/88) where it would perfectly fit. Your contribution is not a question, so if this doesn't change I'll close it.